# sum values s by key python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe like this

```
    animal value
0     dog      1
1     dog      2 
2     dog      3
3     cat      4
```

so i need to sum all values by column `animal`

it's `dog` = `1+2+3` and `cat` is `4`

result should be:

```
    animal value
0     dog      6
1     cat      4
```

i'm trying to do this with some dicts but maybe its more easier way?

should i do `for` loop here?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: ``df.groupby('animal').sum()``. Have a look at [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) for more info